# What are the missing numbers in this group of 7?

Tags: number-sequence

The following groups of 7 number in each line, are related in each line in a unique way:

```
1   3   1.5 12.25   1   2   3

1.5 6   2   42.25   1   3   4

3   6   4   61      2   3   4
```

What are the numbers to replace the "?" in following list?

```
1   5   2.5 32.25   ?   ?   ?
```

Hint: An object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing numbers are:

> 1 2 5

Because:

> Lets say numbers are marked in order like:
>  `x y z n a b c`
>   You can find that:
>  `x = a*b/2`
>  `y = b*c/2`
>  `z = a*c/2`
>
>  `1   5   2.5 32.25   ?   ?   ?`
>  `1 = a*b/2`
>  `5 = b*c/2`
>  `2.5 = a*c/2`
>  `->`
>  `2 = a*b`
>  `10 = b*c`
>  `5 = a*c`
>  `->`
>  `a = 5/c = 2/b`
>  `a*b*c = 5b = 2c`
>  `->`
>  `10a = 5b = 2c` `->`
>  `10 * 1 = 5 * 2 = 2 * 5`
>  So missing numbers are:
>  `1 2 5`
>  But I don't know what middle number `n` should represent.

Comment: Nice. Pretty sure your n is rot(gur fhz bs k^2, l^2 naq m^2). You could then derive a relationship to your a, b and c as well if it helps to confirm your answer...

Comment: Stiv provided an insight (what is this rot(gur fhz bs k^2, l^2 naq m^2)?:)).

Comment: This is the relation of the faces of right angle pyramid